# just wanna highlight some texts when use a browser to view local html

Tags: google-chrome, browser, html, editing

A lot of tutorials exist that can be downloaded from the Internet (with common file types: chm, pdf, html, etc.).

I discovered a problem: I downloaded a Java SE tutorial in HTML format, I use Chrome to view it, and everything works well. However, I want to directly highlight some useful text when I use Chrome to view it.

The HTML files are local, and I know that I could use some software to edit it by adding new tags / styles to the text, but I just want to highlight the text directly in the browser like editing it in Word. Any suggestions? Does Chrome have a plugin to enable this behavior?

As a workaround for now, I use [Evernote Web Clipper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc) for Chrome. It can cut the pages and upload them to Evernote. When I use an Evernote client to read them, I can directly highlight some words which are useful to me.

Comment: Word supports HTML, and since it's local, why not just open it in Word?

Comment: because it is not a single html file. An index and an ocean of html files located at different folders. And each file contains a lot of hyperlinks used to direct to another html file. So, the only way I can read these files is to use browser so that I can follow the tutorials correctly.

Comment: Gotcha.  Do you want to save these highlights permanently?  Which plug-ins have you tried already (if any)?

Comment: no plug-in can support that function  ;(

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of plugins for highlighting web pages out there.

You could try [Yawas](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kjlghdmljfgngjdpeaiogebkiilpiimk) wich does exactly what you seem to look for (highlighting on pages inside of Chrome). While installed you have to edit its settings to store locally the highlights, otherwise it will store them in Google Bookmarks.

You could search for ['highlight' in Chrome Web Store](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/highlight) for some further choices, I think there is a bunch of other solutions there.

Comment: thanks you for you reply. I try some of them, but no one can satisfy me till now. Almost all the extensions are based on bookmark function. They don't change the content of the local html file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try Firefox with the 'Dafizilla ViewSourceWith' plugin. It will open the web page in a editor of your choice.

This will help you until you find (or someone makes) a plugin/extension that allows one to edit web page in place.

Comment: thank you for your answer, right now I don't find any extension can support that function in Chrome. As to Firefox, the plugin you mentioned is not what I really want. I think right now there is no one who makes that extension.

Comment: I rolled back the answer to the original state, as the suggested (and approved by me by mistake) edit was invalid. The screenshot that was added should be posted as a comment or an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I Recommend Is Page Hacker for Firefox , don't know available for chrome or others..

Just enable for any website and then select the text and make it highlight . i am giving a screenshot what it can do..

[image: Page Hacker]

Comment: by mistake i have put it on Catalin's post . its a mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a Desktop Client, I use something for the same requirement and I am ok with it.

The tool name is Amaya. Its from W3C. So it doesn't break the HTML unlike Microsoft Word.

https://www.w3.org/Amaya/User/BinDist.html

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still needs this, you can serve the html file locally and the highlighter will work. A simple way to do this is to download the chrome extension "Web Server for Chrome" and give it the folder of your html files.
I am using the weava highlighter chrome extension, liner also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native "link-to-text" Chrome browser feature, which would have the advantages of 1) more trust-worthy source (arguably), being natively shípped, and 2) syntactically based on URL composition, and (should be) functionally "portable" when sent to others.

Note: I am running Beta; I'm not 100% certain if this is on the stable build's default rollout, you may or may not have to enable a flag for it.